# How to draw a loop passing through by a edge?

Tags: tikz-graphs

I wish draw the following graph:
[image: Figure]

Follows the my attempt:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{pointblack/.style={fill=black, circle, minimum width=3pt, scale=0.6}}
%% 
\node at (2, 0.5) [pointblack] (xhw) {};
\node at (2, -0.5) [pointblack] (xwz) {};
\node at (6, 0) [pointblack] (out) {};
\node at (1,0) [pointblack] (x) {};
\node at (4, 0.5) [pointblack] (y) {};
%%% edges
\draw
(out) to [bend left = 10] (xhw)
(out) to [bend right = 25] (xhw)
(out) to (xwz);
\draw[dashed]
(y) to [bend left = 35] (x)
(y) to [bend right = 45] (x);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Remain draw the dashed loop passing by edge above. How can I to do?

Comment: With a screenshot (and some indication of „above“) it would be easier. However, you probably want to look for in and out, which specify angles of outgoing and incoming lines and bends the line as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 11mm,
pointblack/.style = {fill=black, circle, minimum width=2pt}
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes=pointblack]
\node   (x) {};
\node[above right=of x] (xhw) {};
\node[below right=of x] (xwz) {};
\node[right=of xhw]     (y)   {};
\node[below right=of y] (out) {};
    \end{scope}
%%% edges
\draw[dashed]
    (x) to (y) (y) to [bend right = 45] (x)
    (x) to [out=-60,in=-0,distance=33mm] (x);
\draw 
    (xhw)   to  (out)  
            to [bend right = 45] (xhw)
    (out)   to (xwz);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
in the case, that you like to have more narrow bounding box around picture, than use of the library `bbox` is thw way to go:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox,           % <---
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 11mm,
bezier bounding box,            % <---
pointblack/.style = {fill, circle, outer sep=0pt}
                    ]
 ...
```

[image]